# Spring Boot + Webflux + MongoDB + multiple search criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, criteria-api

I can't find any valubale informations about my problem, therefore my post here.

My service utilizes Spring Boot, Webflux and Mongodb.
My client in React has a search box, you can search by multiple fields. Is there the possibility to use e.g. Search Criteria like:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is("Eric"));

if(condition){
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").is("USA"));
}
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```

Maybe should I use e.g. Query DSL library?

So far I use reactive repository:

```
public interface OfferRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Offer, String> {

    @Query("{'properties': {'$in': ?0}}")
    Flux<Offer> findByPropertiesIds(List<String> propertiesId);
```

but I have no idea how to cope with multiple search criteria (some of them can be optional).